# how can i set custom attribute with @ sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

i cant set a custom attribute for my button. Here is my code please check it, thanks.

```js
btn.setAttribute('@click.prevent', 'login()')
```

```html
<button name="user-auth-submited" id="user-auth-submit" class="user-auth-submit-btn" type="submit">ثبت نام</button>
```

I'm using `alpine.js` and I should have to use the `@` and I want to toggle attribute @click.prevent', 'login() to @click.prevent', 'register()

Comment: What library are you trying to use? In plain JS/HTML, `@click.prevent` has no meaning

Comment: What's such an attribute for? Adding custom attributes to elements is not recommended, and `@` is not a valid character in attribute names. The construction looks like a template placeholder, those are converted to valid code before sending to a browser, it's not useful to set such a placeholder on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set dynamic attributes like this, because it happens after Alpine.js initialization, therefore Alpine.js does not know about it. But there's a different method, in which we use a state variable, where we track whether the user wants to login or register.

```
<div x-data="{login: false}">
    <button @click="login = !login">Switch login/register mode</button></span>
    <button @click.prevent="login_or_register" x-text="login ? 'Login' : 'Register'"></button>

    <script>
        function login_or_register() {
            if (this.login) {
                // Login stuff
            }
            else {
                // Register stuff
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

The first button toggles our new state named `login`. The second button calls the function `login_or_register` in which we access `this.login` variable and execute the selected login or register code. You can easily generalize it to more states if needed as well.